# Documenter.jl build hanging

Tags: julia, documentation, documentation-generation

I am building a documentation with `documenter.jl`. Everything was working fine, until I pulled a new version of the repo from GitHub (and pushed my current repo onto GitHub). I don't think there was anything in the pull that should affect `documenter` at all. Yet, ever since the pull the build is hanging at `[ Info: ExpandTemplates: expanding markdown templates.`. The entire build looks like this:

```
[ Info: SetupBuildDirectory: setting up build directory.
[ Info: Doctest: running doctests.
[ Info: ExpandTemplates: expanding markdown templates.
```

Does anyone have any idea what the reason for this could be?

Comment: Quick question, have you tried re-starting Julia and other things like that? Is it consistently hanging?

Comment: In addition, if you stash your changes and revert to the last known commit that Documenter could successfully build, does that fix it?

Comment: 1. Do you have examples with long runtime? 2. Do you have examples with lots of output? The latter should be fixed with Documenter 0.27, so make sure you are using that.

Comment: No I don't currently have any examples (I excluded all of them). I just updated Documenter (I was at 0.26.3), but for some reason even after the update it still shows me I got 0.26.3?? I'm even more confused now. But also with the 'new' 0.26.3 I still run into the same problem. I'll try to get to the last commit and see if that helps.

Comment: It seems to indeed be a problem with examples. I had an `.md` file with examples in the `src` folder that I didn't reference in `make.jl` so I thought `Documenter` won't see it, but apparently it goes through all files in the folder even if they're not referenced. I didn't know that. Now that I moved the file from that folder it works again. Sooner or later I'll have to add them again though. Then I would need version 0.27? Why do I only have 0.26.3 even after updating?

Comment: Ok I noticed 0.27 just came out 2 days ago on GitHub. Maybe it's not available via `Pkg` yet. I'll see if 0.27 solves the problem. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: There seem to be a related issue here https://github.com/JuliaDocs/Documenter.jl/issues/1414